# PHP fetch association from empty query

Tags: php, mysql, functional-programming

I kind of have a couple of questions on this. I can run the queries in phpmyadmin and see the results, I just don't know how to interpret what I am seeing when it returns nothing.

Q1: What happens if I skip the whole count rows thing and just return a result by association from a query that is empty? In this example, say that there is no planet matching this criterion, but I still attempt to fetch association from the result. If I returned this function, would it give me a NULL, a zero, an error?

```
function getPlanet($galaxy, $system, $planet) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `planets` WHERE planet_galaxy = ? AND planet_system = ? AND planet_planet = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param("iii", $galaxy, $system, $planet);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rslt = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
    $stmt->close();

    return $rslt;
}
```

Q2: Say every one of my planets could have an occupier (planet_user_id). So planet_user_id would be some random number matching a user_id if someone is there and it would be '' if no one is there. What would this return if I called this and no one was there?

```
function getPlanetOwner($galaxy, $system, $planet) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT planet_user_id FROM `planets` WHERE planet_galaxy = ? AND planet_system = ? AND planet_planet = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param("iii", $galaxy, $system, $planet);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rslt = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();

    return $rslt;
}
```

Thanks for clearing this up a bit for me. Im pretty new to this jazz. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query returns no result. $rslt will be false.

If you want to do something in this case you can put an if in your code based on it being false.

```
If(!$rslt)
{
Echo "I have no result";
}
```

BTW. Column planet_planet made me lol.